# If T is bounded, is it closed if X and Y are not Banach?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $T:D_T\subseteq X\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator between normed spaces. If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, then it can easily be shown that $T$ is closed. But what if $X$ and $Y$ are NOT complete? If we assume that $x_n\in D_T$, $x_n\to x, Tx_n\to y$, then since $T$ is bounded, $Tx=y$ If $x\in D_T$, but how do we guarantee that $x\in D_T$?

Comment: In your last sentence, you say "since $T$ is closed."  Isn't that what you want to prove?

Comment: Yes I meant to say since $T$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, $T$ doesn't have to be closed.  For instance, let $D$ be any dense subset of a Banach space $B$ and consider the identity $T = \text{Id} : D \to D$.  Then $T$ is bounded, but it's not closed.  In particular, if $v \in B \setminus D$, then there is a sequence $(v_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq D$ such that $v_{n} \to v$ and $T(v_{n}) = v_{n}$ so $T(v_{n}) \to v$.  Nonetheless, $v \notin D$ so $T$ is not closed.  An explicit example of this is $D = \mathbb{Q}^{d}$ and $B = \mathbb{R}^{d}$ with the Euclidean norm.

Comment: This is contrary to what my definition of closed says. Is there some intuition you can give as to why $T$ would be closed? Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of closed?

Comment: $T$ is closed if and only if for $x_n\in D_T, x_n\to x, Tx_n\to y$, then $x\in D_T$ and $Tx=y$. So to show that $T$ is closed, we have to show both that $x\in D_T$, and that $Tx=y$

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right.  I just checked and the definition of Reed and Simon, vol. 1, is the same as you just gave.  I'll edit my answer.